# How do I disable regular Android notifications from Google asking to verify my phone number?

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow, google

This has started happening recently.  It seems like I am getting at least one notification every day or two now on my Android phone from Google saying:

```
**Verify your phone number**
Google can warn you of suspicious activity in your 
account & you can more easily connect with friends
in Google services.
```

I don't want to see this notification any more (it plays a loud sound every time, and the other morning it actually woke me up!) and I also am not going to verify my phone number.   How can I make these notifications stop?

Comment: "*go into your App Settings, locate "Google Play Services" app and you should (hopefully) see an option to "Show Notifications" - I unchecked this and the issue immediately went away*"  per LP627 [post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/gmail/FG27eZqtjk0/7UQwsaTICAAJ)

Answer (score -1):

The app is Google Play Services. Disable notifications in Settings > Apps

Comment: What is the risk of masking other, important, notifications? Are there any others?